# tab to html <select> element

Tags: html, forms, select, drop-down-menu, tabs

I have a `FORM`, and within it several `INPUT` and `SELECT` elements.
My problem is that I can tab the `INPUTs` but not the `SELECT` drop downs.
I tried the `tabindex="2"` attribute, but it didn't affect anything.

Is there way to do this?

Comment: Which browser and what version?

Comment: I tested on Firefox, Chrome, IE on Win 7, and they tab to `select` OK, even when not using `tabindex` at all. You need to post more information, as the problem may be either in elsewhere in your code (perhaps JavaScript stealing focus) or in your expectations on what should happen when an element is tabbed to. Try using `outline: solid red` in CSS to see which element is focused.

Comment: Here is a sample of my code. If it changes anything I'm in php, but I'm not able to get it to tab in html ether.
<table>
<tr>
<td><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="location" size=17 maxlength=22/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date" size=12 maxlength=10/></td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Please do not post a duplicate. Instead, improve the original question by giving sufficient information.